# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression. Escaping characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I'm trying to show a div element with the id "online-payments" if a specific radio box is selected during the checkout process.

So far I have the following:

```
<div id="online-payments" style="display: none;">
    Test
</div>
```

And for the javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("radio[@name='payment\[method\]']").click(function(){
if (jQuery("radio[@name='payment\[method\]']:checked").val() == 'checkmo')
jQuery("#online-payments").show();
});
});
```

This is a Magento store so im using the no-conflict mode because of the prototype libraries.

The problem comes down to the radio's name. It's **payment[method]** by default on Magento (I've tried to change it, but it looks like it would give me more work than I had anticipated).

So it really comes down to escaping those brackets [ ], which I thought I did, but even then it's throwing me this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: radio[@name='payment[method]']
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several problems there:

1. You're using an attribute selector, but with an invalid name (`@name`). Attribute names cannot start with `@`.
2. There's also no need for the backslashes as long as you use quotes (which you are, [single quotes are fine](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#strings)). (And the ones you have aren't ending up as part of the selector, to put a backslash in a selector when the selector is in a JavaScript string, you have to escape the backslash as `\\`.)
3. `radio` isn't a tag name.

Perhaps you wanted:

```
jQuery("input[type=radio][name='payment[method]']")
```

jQuery offers an extension which is `:radio`, but using it isn't recommended, for the reasons discussed [on its API page](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/) (basically, jQuery can't hand it off to the browser's native `querySelector` / `querySelectorAll`).